# Django customize model fields to show on template

Tags: python, django

I'm in a weird situation. I have following model. On a template i render only name and author. The thing is there is **edit display** button, when click on edit display. It should show all the fields name to choose. When i choose fields and save table's element should be updated as chosen fields.

models.py

```
class Finding(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    isbn = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey()
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    shop = models.ManyToManyField()
```

template(findings.html)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td>{{author}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I was thinking about using a session. But this should be dynamic and permanent. Every user may change showing fields according to their preference. How can i achieve this.

Comment: Use simple `show` and `hide` functions of javascript. Also, you need to use `form` to submit data.

Comment: @AnkushRaghuvanshi this must be permanent. So just a show and hide is not an option i think. For a permanent solution it should be stored in DB

Answer (score 0):

You can create a checkedbox form and handle the values in the view to return appropriate html content, for example (form):

```
class CheckBox(forms.Form):
    name = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

View:

```
def your_view(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():

            if request.POST["name"]:
                name = 1

            if request.POST["author"]:
                author = 1

return render(request, 'app/findings.html', {'name':name, 'author':author})
```

Then in your template, you can use django template if statement to check which has been selected, for example:

```
{% if name == 1 %}
 <td>{{name}}</td>
{% endif %}
{% if author == 1 %}
 <td>{{author}}</td>
{% endif %}
```

I hope this gives you some direction.